# How to get from n to n items in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create an android app which pulls first 1-10 documents in the mongodb collection and show those item in a list, then later when the list reaches the end i want to pull 11-20 documents in the mongodb collection and it goes on.

```
def get_all_tips(from_item, max_items):
    db = client.MongoTip
    tips_list = db.tips.find().sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(max_items).skip(from_item)
    if tips_list.count() > 0:
        from bson import json_util
        return json_util.dumps(tips_list, default=json_util.default), response_ok
    else:
        return "Please move along nothing to see here", response_invalid

    pass
```

But the above code does not work the way i intended but rather it returns from `from_item` to `max_items`

Example: calling get_all_tips(3,4)

It returns:

> Document 3, Document 4, Document 5, Document 6

I'm expecting:

> Document 3, Document 4

Comment: You are doing it correctly,are you sure you are sending 4 in max_items

db.tips.find().limit(4).skip(3)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are specifying two parameters.

1. from_item: which is the starting index of the documents to return
2. max_items: number of items to return

Therefore calling get_all_tips(3,4) will return 4 documents starting from document 3 which is exactly what's happening.

Proposed fixes:

1. If you want it to return documents 3 and 4 call get_all_tips(3,2) instead, which means return a maximum of two documents starting from 3.
2. If you'd rather like to specify the start and end indexes in your function, I recommend the following changes:

   ```
   def get_all_tips(from_item, to_item):
       if to_item < from_item:
           return "to_item must be greater than from item", bad_request
       db = client.MongoTip
       tips_list = db.tips.find().sort([['_id', -1]]).limit(to_item - from_item).skip(from_item)
   ```

That being said, I'd like to point out that MongoDb documentation does not recommend use of skip for pagination for large collections.
[MongoDb 3.2 cursor.skip](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.skip/)